# Is there a finite or at least recursive axiomatization for the theory of the rational ordered field?

Tags: model-theory

Consider the structure $(\mathbb{Q},+,-,*,0,1,<)$ What is an axiomatization for the complete theory of that structure? Is there a finite or at worst recursive axiomatization for the complete theory of that structure?

Comment: Would that give an axiomatization of the theory of $(\Bbb N,\dots)$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, but [finding](http://www.math.umd.edu/~laskow/713/Spring17/carolslides.pdf) $\mathbb{N}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is nontrivial.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Ok. Now, pardon my ignorance, the reason I phrased my comment as a question: Once we've found that $\Bbb N$ it follows that the answer to the current question is no, right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Yes, per Tarski $Th(\mathbb{N})$ (and so $Th(\mathbb{Q})$ as well) isn't first-order definable in $\mathbb{N}$. This is a (much) stronger condition than mere non-recursive-axiomatizability, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post%27s_theorem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, $\mathbb{Z}$ [is first-order definable](http://www.math.umd.edu/%7Elaskow/713/Spring17/carolslides.pdf) in the ring of rationals! So the latter's theory is exactly as complicated as the former's (interpreting $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$ is an easy exercise), hence not recursively axiomatizable.

The definition of $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$ is however quite complicated; it is open whether the *Diophantine* theory of $\mathbb{Q}$ is decidable ("Hilbert's $10$th problem for $\mathbb{Q}$"). See [this survey of Poonen](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/aws2003.pdf) for general aspects of Diophantine complexity.

---

That said, we can give a snappy axiomatization of $\mathbb{Q}$ *relative to* $Th(\mathbb{Z})$.

Let $\zeta(x)$ be a formula defining $\mathbb{Z}$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Then $Th(\mathbb{Q})$ is axiomatized by:

- $Th(\mathbb{Z})^\zeta$, the relativization of each sentence in $Th(\mathbb{Z})$ to $\zeta$.
- The usual ordered field axioms.
- The "generation" axiom that every $x$ is of the form $y\over z$ for some $y,z\in\mathbb{Z}$.

It's not actually *quite* trivial that the conjunction $T$ of the above sentences axiomatizes $Th(\mathbb{Q})$; while given $M,N\models T$ we have $\zeta^M\equiv\zeta^N$, we still need to check that we don't get any first-order differences when we look beyond their "$\zeta$-parts." In general, two structures "generated" in the same way by elementarily equivalent substructures will themselves be elementarily equivalent; this can be proved by EF-games.